# Drupal 7: how to rewrite rules replacement patterns programmatically

Tags: 7, rules

i try to create different rule conditions or actions and need to rewrite different replacement patterns. for example:

defined replacement patterns:

```
 [loaded-points:value] [vote:value]
```

i want:

```
 if [loaded-points:value] >= 0

 [vote:value] = - abs([vote:value])

 else 

 [vote:value] = abs([vote:value])
```

the following variables are available and may be used by PHP code:

```
 $loaded_points, $vote
```

my action as php code:

```
  if(isset($loaded_points, $vote['value'])) {
  $vote_value = (int)abs(round($vote['value']));
  if($loaded_points >= 0) {
   $vote['value'] = -$vote_value;
  } else {
   $vote['value'] = $vote_value;   
  }
 }
```

in the next action i have the same values as before php action.